# How to toggle variable in Codesys CFC by pressing same momentary button?

Tags: codesys, iec61131-3

The question pity much say it all.

I have a momentary button. I click it one time, variable `start` gets `HIGH`. I click it another time variable `start` goes `LOW`

Sounds like trivial task, but with САС I was not able to do that. That is because of data flow. The last task always apply to variable.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out very simple task

[image]

`envKey` is a global PLC keyboard var and `keyStart` identifier of Start key.

What is happening `R_TRIG` create one pulse when button is pressed.